# For Loop not printing correctly

Tags: c++

just practicing doing some c++ exercises.

In my code I do not understand why my for loop is not printing the array from highest to lowest. It just prints 0.

```
int main()
{
    int num[2];
    int* ptr = num;

    cin >> *ptr;
    cin >> *(ptr + 1);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i- -)
        cout << *(ptr + i) << endl;
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i - -) cout << *(ptr + i) << endl;` should be `for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) cout << *(ptr + i) << endl;`

Comment: check your increment condition in loop

Comment: In my test condition i <= 2 doesn’t this equal to i is 1, which is 1 less than or equal 2, which is true. Then why doesn’t it work? Also I am decreasing each time.

Comment: ***Also I am decreasing each time.*** Not with what you typed. I edited but left the space between the - and -

Comment: Also if you were decreasing the loop condition would be wrong. `i` would always be less than 2.

Comment: I do not understand what is wrong with my for loop. The test condition 1<=2 would make the test true which means it would execute code body. Then after it will decreases i to 0. Then test 0<=2 which would equal true then execute the code body. So what is going on?

Comment: After `i` goes less than 0 you will have undefined behavior. Assuming you meant to write `for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i--)` instead of `for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i- -)`

Comment: From what I understand is variable i value will decrease all the way to 0. Then 0<=2 which is true. Then decrement, i=0-1 which is 0 still isn’t it?

Comment: Yes it will decrease past 0 if you change the code `for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i--)` however that will cause undefined behavior because you access outside the bounds of your num array.

Comment: Your "answer" is pretty much correct even though it shouldn't be posted as an answer. Once `i` gets negative you're accessing invalid array indices, the behavior of which is undefined. Therefore, anything can happen.

Answer (score 0):

Is this correct from what I tried to understand?

for(int i=1; i<=2; i--)
cout << *(ptr+i);

Variable i will decrement past 0 to negative -
Then it will keep decrement and testing? -1<=2 , -2<=-2, -3<=2 , making the loop never ending?

Answer (score 0):

*printing the array from highest to lowest.*

You did it almost correctly, except the loop condition. You should iterate indexes from the highest to the lowest, 1, then 0. In other words, starting from the index 1, decreasing the index until 0, and exit the loop if index violates the condition.

```
for (int i = 1; i >= 0; i--)
    cout << *(ptr + i) << endl;
```